# Copy table from SQL Server 2008 to MS Access 2007

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, converters

Firstly, For Those who would like to ask WHY on earth am I DOWNSIZING from SQL SERVER to ACCESS, let me tell you the scenario.
There are some PC's with very low configuration, (256 MB RAM, 2GHzProcessor) I cannot install SQL Server. Hence I want major operations to carry out on SQL server and some data retrieving and auditing work to be done on Slower machine.

So here we go:
I want to copy table from SQL Server to MS Access 2007. I tried:

1)Connect to sql server, fill a datatable object by reading table from sql server.

2) Create a connection to MS Access, and use Dataadapter.Update method to update table to MS Access database.

However 2nd step is not working although its not throwing any error. Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"initial catalog=DBTempleERM;user id=aditya;password=Aditya_ravi$;Data Source=adityalappy\sqlexpress");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM donationdetails", cnn);
cnn.Open();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable donationdetails = new DataTable();
sDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
sDA.Fill(donationdetails);

MessageBox.Show(donationdetails.Rows.Count.ToString());

OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Aditya_ravi$;Data Source=C:\dbt.accdb");
oleConn.Open();
OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleComm);
OleDbCommandBuilder oCb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oDA);
oDA.Update(donationdetails);
```

No error is thrown at the end of the execution, but I cannot see any records copied from SQL Server to MS Access.

I learnt that SQL Bulk copy cannot be used to copy from SQL Server to Access.

I also want to add the primary key from SQL Server table to MS Access table.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21466/Very-Fast-Table-Copy-from-an-ODBC-Source-into-Micr

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Just to make sure you know about them, there are some options down from 'full SQL Server' that may be worth considering: SQL Compact 4.0 (or 3.5) runs in-proc @ http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876 ; SQL 2012's "LocalDB" runs as a separate process, but lighter weight than 'full' SQL database engine @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx ; and, of course, the 'regular' SQL Server Express edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use SSIS to do this for you.

You can create a SSIS package to copy a sql table to MS access.

If you want to initiate by .NET then create a SSIS package and call it from .NET

[For details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237591/can-you-run-an-ssis-task-from-net)

Comment: Please speak English. "u" is not an English word.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, oDA is not connected to any table on the Access side:

```
oDA.Update(donationdetails);
```

So even though you have all the data in a DataTable, you haven't got a target to copy it into.

I don't think this is the best approach, but that's the core of why your code isn't working as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Ancient question, but I'm betting the RowState of all your rows in donationdetails were Unchanged, so the DataAdapter treats them as "I don't need to do anything with this row."

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataset object instead of datatable.

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
sDA.Fill(ds,tablename);

oDA.Update(ds);
```